# ANSI C splitting string

Tags: c, string, split, ansi-c

Hey there!
I'm stuck on an **ANSI C** problem which I think should be pretty trivial (it is at least in any modern language :/).

The (temporary) goal of my script is to split a string (array of char) of 6 characters ("123:45") which represents a timestamp minutes:seconds (for audio files so it's ok to have 120 minutes) into just the minutes and just the seconds.

I tried several approaches - a general one with looking for the ":" and a hardcoded one just splitting the string by indices but none seem to work.

```
void _splitstr ( char *instr, int index, char *outstr ) {
char temp[3]; 
int i; 
int strl = strlen ( instr );
if ( index == 0 ) {
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        if ( temp[i] != '\0' ) {
            temp[i] = instr[i];
        }
    }
} else if ( index == 1 ) {
    for ( i = 6; i > 3; i-- ) {
            temp[i] = instr[i];
        }
    }
strcpy ( outstr, temp );
}
```

Another "funny" thing is that the string length of an char[3] is 6 or 9 and never actually 3. What's wrong with that?

Comment: homework? no problem if it is, just let us know

Comment: Your code tries to put 3 characters into `temp` (which it can hold) and then use `temp` in a "string" function. A string needs to be terminated by a null byte. Your `temp` does not have space for the null byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/). As simple as it can get.

```
    char time[] = "123:45";
    int minutes, seconds;

    sscanf(time, "%d:%d", &minutes, &seconds);
```

This works best if you can be sure that time string syntax is always valid. Otherwise you must add check for that. On success, sscanf function *returns the number of items succesfully read* so it's pretty easy to detect errors too.

Working example: http://ideone.com/vVoBI

Comment: God this could have spared me a whole day of frantic debugging, thanks!
I didn't think it would be that easy >.>

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
int seconds, minutes;
minutes = atoi(instr);
while(*instr != ':' && *++instr != '\0');
seconds = atoi(instr);
```

Should be pretty fast.

Comment: Although I think this can crash with a SIGSEGV or similar (or possibly produce nonsense results) if `instr` happens not to contain a colon character, which is a little harsh.

Comment: @Simon Nickerson, @Athabaska Dick: indeed. it's not forgiving for errors. I'll add the `NULL` check. Slightly slower but shouldn't be a problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like that:

```
void break_string(const char* input, char* hours, char* minutes)
{
    if(input == 0 || hours == 0 || minutes == 0)
        return;

    while(*input != ':')
        *hours++ = *input++;

    *hours = '\0';
    ++input;

    while(*minutes++ = *input++);

    return;
}
```

Here is the same function a bit simplified:

```
void break_string(const char* input, char* hours, char* minutes)
{
    if(input == 0 || hours == 0 || minutes == 0)
        return;

    while(*input != ':')
    {
        *hours = *input;
        ++hours;
        ++input;
    }
    *hours = '\0';

    ++input; //ignore the ':' part
    while(*input)
    {
        *minutes = *input;
        ++minutes;
        ++input;
    }
    *minutes = '\0';

    return;
}

int main()
{
    char* test = "123:45";
    char* minutes   = malloc( sizeof(char) * 12 );
    char* hours     = malloc( sizeof(char) * 12 );
    break_string( test , hours , minutes );
    printf("%s , %s \n" , hours , minutes ); 
    //...
    free( minutes );
    free( hours ) ;
}
```

Comment: Why `malloc` and copy something that's already in memory? You could just keep two pointers to the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically three options

- change the input string (can't be a string literal)
- copy data to output strings (input can be a literal)
- transform sequences of characters to numbers

Changing the input string implies transforming `"123:45"` to `"123\0" "45"` with an embedded null.

Copying data implies managing storage for the copy.

Transforming sequences of characters implies using, for example, `strtol`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't putting a terminating null on your string in temp[], so when you do a strlen(temp), you are accessing arbitrary memory.

Using your known lengths, you can use something like this:

```
char temp[4];
if (index==0)
{
  strncpy(temp, instr, 3);
  temp[3] = 0;
}
else if (index==1)
{
  strncpy(temp, instr+4, 2);
  temp[2] = 0;
}
strcpy(outstr, temp);
```

But, I'll caution that I've skipped all sorts of checking for valid lengths in instr and outstr.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
char *mins, *secs;
mins = str;
while(*(++str) != ':');
str[0] = '\0';
secs = s + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, I have ignore the "index" argument above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void _splitstr ( char *instr, char *outstr ) {
        char temp[10];
        char* end = strchr(instr, ':');
        int i = 0;

        if(end != 0) {
                while(instr != end)
                        temp[i++] = *instr++;
                temp[i] = '\0';
                strcpy(outstr, temp);
        } else {
                outstr = '\0';
        }
}
```